# rsyslog cron.daily warning message

Tags: linux, cron, logrotate, rsyslogd

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and cron is emailing me the following message

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
Warning: Stopping rsyslog.service, but it can still be activated by:
 syslog.socket
```

I have not made any changes to logrotate.conf or /etc/logrotate.d/ rsyslog. Rsyslog is still running and logging correctly. I do see messages in syslog indicating that systemd is starting rsyslog more than once within milliseconds. I’m trying to find out the cause of this error. If it’s not critical then I want to suppress it.

Comment: Looks like the syslog service is crashing and then being re spawned by the syslog.socket service. Try stopping and disabling the syslog.socker service and just enabling/running syslog.service.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I made changes this morning and now I’m waiting to see what happens tomorrow.